# No matching function to call with constructor(T* data)

Tags: c++, function, constructor

My class node is a basic implementation of a simple Tree where each node has two child nodes. I've read 10 answers regarding the error message, but I could not figure out, where this goes wrong.

> error: no matching function for call to '`Lib::Node<Math::Expression*>::Node(Math::Expression*&)`'

```
Lib::Node< Math::Expression* > Dirac::DiracParser::parse(std::string str) const{
    typedef Math::Expression* Expr; // Don't do this, as pointed out by Lightness Races in Orbit
    typedef Lib::Node<Expr> ExprNode;
    ExprNode root; // works
    Expr e = new Math::UnknownExpression();
    ExprNode root2(e); // yields error message
    return root;
}
```

And the definition

```
namespace Lib{
    template <typename T>
    class Node{
        public:
            Node() : empty(true){}
            Node(T* t) : data(t), empty(false){}
            Node(T* t, Node<T>* l) : data(t), left(l), empty(false){}
            Node(T* t, Node<T>* l, Node<T>* r) : data(t), left(l), right(r), empty(false){}
            Node(const Node<T>& n) : data(n.data), left(n.left), right(n.right), empty(false){}
            inline bool isEmpty(){
                return empty;
            }
            ~Node(){}
            T* data;
            Node* left;
            Node* right;
        private:
            bool empty;
    };
}
```

To my understanding, the error refers to my 2nd constructor not being implemented. I think I might have to do some pointer gymnastics to pass it correctly, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Present your [MCVE]. We went over this on your last question.

Comment: The constructor of `Node<Expr>` takes `Expr*` (a pointer to `Expr`, aka a pointer to pointer to `Math::Expression`) as its parameter. You are passing `Expr`. You probably want `Node<Math::Expression>` instead.

Comment: Top tip: don't hide pointer types behind pointless (lol) type aliases. It leads to confusion, like the confusion you're experiencing right now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought (again) that this is solvable without the example

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you. Post it as an answer and I'll make sure to accept it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the advice. I changed the typedefs in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instantiated `Lib::Node< Math::Expression* >`, so `T` is `Math::Expression*`. The constructor accepts a `T*`.

When you substitute `T`, the argument `T*` becomes `Math::Expression**`. You try to pass a `Math::Expression*` to the constructor, but there is no constructor that would accept it.